# How to make categories listing pagination in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I made a category listing page using `WP_Term_Query` but I need pagination that will paginate this page.

```
<?php
if (is_category())
    $current_cat = get_query_var('cat');
$arg = array( 
    'taxonomy'=> 'category', 
    'child_of'=> $current_cat,
    'number' => 2,      
);
$term_query = new WP_Term_Query($arg);
?>
<div class="wb-subcategories">
<?php
foreach ($term_query->terms as $subcat):
    $subcat_link = get_category_link( $subcat->term_id );
    ?>
    <div class="wb-subcat">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $subcat_link ); ?>">           
            <div class="subcat-img">
                <div class="overlay"></div>
                <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/happy-woman.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="subcat-title">
                <h3><?php echo $subcat->name; ?></h3>
                <span>( <?php echo $subcat->count ?> )</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>                          
    <?php
endforeach;
?>
</div>
```

I'm already using `paginate_links();` function but it's not working. It shows the pagination number but paginate number link not working.

```
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
$max_num_pages =  ceil($term_query->query_vars['total_category']/ $term_query->query_vars['number']);

echo paginate_links(array(
    'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link($big))),
    'format' => '%#%',
    'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
    'total' => $max_num_pages,
    'offset' => $offset
));
```

I only need pagination for categories list, not categories post.